# QOS - the need for it and verifying it

Tags: network, qos, mpls, voip

Just some straightforward questions,  hope gurus here can shed some light

1) show int - output queue -> this is the hardware queue (tx-ring)  or this is the software queue ?
if I see drop, this means it is definitely congested ?

======

2) QOS classification -> using MCQ, it is said that we can classify at inbound and queue at outbound. But it seems to me, no matter what, classification is still needed when defining an egress policy.

```
e.g.
( service-policy test
 class test-class  <---  isn't this already some-how a classification ?
)
```

So why bother to class at ingress ?

======

3) Just a silly question - Is there anyway we can "determine"  if a particular traffic is ingressing from a LLQ/PQ of its uplink ?
I think my MPLS provider is not sending my voice traffic to me on its' router's priority queue.  Anyway to verify that ?  or the only way is to ask the provider to show me its policy-map ?

Thanks and hope to hear from you guys.